# How do I copy text to the clipboard within an ajax callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

I need to copy text to the clipboard within an AJAX success callback function. In my code below the text is transferred correctly in to the `textarea`, but it is not copied to the clipboard.

The code works fine outside of the AJAX callback function. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<textarea id="checktext" name="text"></textarea>
```

```js
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  success: function(result) {
    document.getElementById("checktext").innerText = result;
    // also tried: document.getElementById("checktext").innerHtml = result;
    // also tried: $('#checktext').val(result);

    document.querySelector("#checktext").select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }
})
```

Comment: javascript will execute document.getElementById(), document.querySelector() and document.execCommand() at the same time because it is declared withit the same function. You need a callback-function after you filled you textarea with your result.

Comment: `execCommand()` only works when triggered within a user-initiated action, such as a click event. If you're executing this logic when the page loads, it won't work.

Comment: Here's a working example showing what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/rktxzjd2/

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers. Is there any way I can achieve my goal? I need this functionality within the callback. :(

Comment: Yes, execute this logic within a user-initiated event handler.